# How to speed up git fetch from a mapped network drive

Tags: git

I have a bare git repo on a network drive.  I have a local working repo on my machine where I make my edits, and then I push/pull to the bare repo on the network drive.  My machine runs Windows.

When I'm at work, the connection to the network drive is fast and fetch/push/pull all work within a reasonable amount of time.

When I'm working remotely, I connect via VPN, which is obviously a slower connection.  fetch/push/pull over the VPN is orders of magnitude slower.  I'm looking for a way to speed it up.

I suspect that when git is doing things like "delta compression", etc, that it may be wasting bandwidth by downloading information to my computer, compressing it, and then sending the compressed data to my repo.  The compression step makes sense if the remote git repo is on a remote computer system that can locally compute the compression before sending data over the network.  However, a mapped network drive is just a remote filesystem - so I'm wondering if I can speed things up by skipping the compression step.

1)  Is git doing what I think it's doing?
2)  Can git distinguish between repos that are on a remote computer system vs. a remote filesystem?
3)  Is it possible to disable the compression steps for remote file systems?
4)  Is this the best way to do accomplish what I'm trying to do, or is there a better approach?

Eg:

```
$ git fetch
remote: Enumerating objects: 10, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (10/10), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.  <-- Is this wasted time/bandwidth?
remote: Total 6 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (6/6), done.
From <repo>
   5bf23b5..fbc1b90  master     -> origin/master
```

Answer (score 2):

> I suspect that when git is doing things like "delta compression", etc, that it may be wasting bandwidth by downloading information to my computer, compressing it, and then sending the compressed data to my repo. The compression step makes sense if the remote git repo is on a remote computer system that can locally compute the compression before sending data over the network. However, a mapped network drive is just a remote filesystem - so I'm wondering if I can speed things up by skipping the compression step.

Your analysis here is correct.  However, there's no way to do that other than to tell Git that the file system *is* local, by using a path name instead of a scheme-oriented URL.

That is:

```
git clone https://example.com/path/to/repo.git
```

or:

```
git clone ssh://user@example.com/path/to/repo.git
```

go over a network, but so does:

```
git clone file://path/to/repo.git
```

As far as Git is concerned, that repository is on a different machine entirely, that runs its own Git server.  (Under the covers, Git spawns off another Git to act as the server, so that both are running on the same machine.)  However:

```
git clone /path/to/repo.git
```

tells Git that it should *not* treat the other repository as being on a different machine.  Instead, it can directly access the files.

Whether this will really much if any faster, or in the end, *slower*, is unclear, but at least you won't have Git wasting time compressing.  Instead, you'll waste time accessing.

A better solution is to avoid using the networked drive feature entirely: find a server on which that drive really *is* local (or at least quick to access), and point your computer at that computer.  Get *that* computer to access the repository (quickly), compress the data (using its CPUs to good effort), send *compressed* data to your computer over the slow network, and then keep a *local* (non-network-drive) copy of the repository.  The first clone will be slow, but after that, the compressing and have/want protocol that keeps the data transfer to a minimum will mean that you don't have to send many megabytes across the slow part of the system.

Comment: Thank you for you response.  Something seems off, tho, because my current setup DOES use the file path.  i.e. "git remote -v" gives  "origin D:/path/to/repo".  It is not a scheme based URL.  So I wonder why it still behaves this way?

Your last paragraph is the best solution, and one I would prefer, but I don't own the hosting hardware.  I'll try to see if I can convince the powers that be to allow a git instance on their hardware.

Comment: Ah, perhaps `--local` was defeated by the `D:` leading path bit. I don't actually use Git on Windows, so there are a lot of edge cases I wouldn't know the answers to in the first place. Plus, there are multiple different ports of Git to Windows, each of which has its own quirks...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar, if not the same, problem.

I was using `//<ip>/<path>` remote style when connected locally, but via VPN speed was less than 2KB/sec and it would take minutes for just a few changes in the commit.

Looking this article I used: `file://<ip>/<path>` and that did the trick. Bandwidth among the transfers increased to MBs/sec.

Thanks for the info @torek!

Comment: Please don't add _thanks_ as answers. They don't actually provide an answer to the question, and can be perceived as noise by its future visitors. Once you [earn](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472) enough [reputation](/help/whats-reputation), you will gain privileges to [upvote answers](/help/privileges/vote-up) you like. This way future visitors of the question will see a higher vote count on that answer, and the answerer will also be rewarded with reputation points. See [Why is voting important](/help/why-vote).