What is the most efficient way to pull the latest changes in a big repository mounted on a network share (NFS)?
Given:

An Azure storage container (sku = Premium_LRS, kind = BlockBlobStorage) with a big git repo (a few GB)
The container is mounted on a Linux k8s pod using NFS.
Nightly cron job pulling the latest from the origin.

The reason for all of this is our desire to feed our GitHub repo to Azure AI Search. We opted for the low tech approach of cloning the repo to an Azure Storage container and specifying the latter as a data source in Azure AI Search.
The way the cron job pulls the latest is by running these two commands:

git fetch
git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD

The first command may take about a minute. But the second takes about 30 mins. Although it is not a problem for us, I am curious if this can be improved by running some other git commands.
EDIT 1
If we could break git reset --hard into lower level infrastructure commands, then I could time them individually and maybe this would tell us how to optimize it.

30 minutes feels like a long time to locally unpack the changes that were downloaded over the network in only 1 minute. I would test doing it a second time shortly after the first one and see if it finishes quickly. If it's very fast because there are no changes, repeat the test again after just a small number of changes have occurred (instead of a full day's worth). If either of these 2 tests were slow, then I'm thinking the problem is unlikely to be Git related, and is more likely a network issue, perhaps related to the share.

Another thing you can test is cloning the repo into the local container instead of to a share, just for time comparison purposes. If that's super fast, then you know the share is the bottleneck. I would guess Git pack compression can account for maybe up to 5X difference? The other 6X difference on top of it could possibly be coming from latency of copying lots of tiny files across a share, if the repo has a lot of changes each day.

How do you know the unpack occurs locally? After all the git repo is on the network share. Does it use TEMP directory? Or .git directory? The git clone operation takes about 7 hours, which is more than 10 times slower than locally. I know NFS and the network latency is to blame.

Sorry about that. It was less than 2 hours ago that I wrote that first comment, and I'm not sure what I was thinking there. It's as if I forgot the repo was on a network drive, until the second half of the last sentence.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53873598/184546
